# Rendering an abstract class with italics (class diagram with mermaid)

Tags: mermaid

Mermaid provides annotations as a means to differentiate abstract classes in UML class diagrams. This is not universally usable, for instance, if an abstract class implements interfaces.

Ideally, an abstract class would be rendered with its name in italics. I tried to do so with the following CSS file:

```css
.abstract {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Which I applied to one of the examples:

```
class Animal:::abstract {
    -int sizeInFeet
    -canEat()
}
```

But as the style applies to the whole node, not only the class name is rendered in italics, properties and methods are so too:

[image: Class node with all text in italics]

Would there be another strategy to render an abstract class with its name in italics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a more specific CSS selector:

```css
.abstract .classTitle {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

[image: Class node with an italic title and non-italic body]